# Android Get Menu from Res/menu Programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml

I am creating a custom BottomNavigation using LinearLayout. I want to use `Menu` as items.

```
<com.sam.grocerystore.views.XBottomNavigation
    android:id="@+id/customBottomNav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"/>
```

In Java

```
XBottomNavigation xNav = new XBottomNavigation(this);

xNav.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_nav_menu);
```

In XBottomNavigation

```
public void inflateMenu(@MenuRes int menuRes){
    Menu menu = getMenuFromResID(menuRes);
}
```

Can someone help me to create `getMenuFromResID` funtion;

Comment: Why can't you just pass the menu thought the XML like: `app:menu="@menu/bttm_nag"`  then getting the menu using typedarray inside your custom bottom navigation view class

Comment: My custom class is subclass of Linearlayout. Is this work for this. Or I have to create custom typedarray.

Comment: Best way is to check  bottomnavigation source code to see how they implemented it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I solved this problem using `PopupMenu`

```
public void inflateMenu(@MenuRes int menuRes) {
    PopupMenu p = new PopupMenu(getContext(), null);
    menu = p.getMenu();
    new MenuInflater(getContext()).inflate(menuRes, menu);
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        // yourFunctionToCreateItemUI(i, item);
    }
}
```